# How can I access a dictionary across different programs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The setup in Python as follows:

1. Program 1 starts
2. Program 1 creates a dictionary in the form myDictionary = {'':{'':''}}
3. Program 1 exits
4. Program 2 starts
5. # At this point, i want to access myDictioanry.
6. Program 2 exits

To be precise, I am storing cookies in that dictionary. My webapp testing application requires me to login all the users once. Once logged in, the second program must test it for some other things which use these cookies. I want to skip the login module and get the cookies from the previous program itself.

Is there a way to store and access this dictionary across programs in Python? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per phro's answer, you can't expect to be able to persist data across python instances without storing it somewhere.  Having said that, you could [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle), [dump it as json](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [shelve it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), or, if things get hairy, [sqlite it](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution but you could [pickle it](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle).

Comment: If I will be have a million entries in it. Would that be the best solution? My dictionary involves storing of cookie - not a big one, but about 50 words or so, which still makes it huge when it comes to storing..

Comment: Well if it's a million that's one thing, in that case you'll want a proper database but if it's only 50 pickling won't kill performance but again it's not very elegant. Perhaps you should consider a small database like sqlite?